# dayRender stops working when Fullcalendar is using view: resourceTimelineWeek [V4.0.1]

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, outsystems

I have a project in hands that requires me to use the resources premium function from fullcalendar. I need to use the dayRender option to create a div in each day for css customization, however it seems the dayRender is not even called (I used a debugger on the function to test it) when the view is as resourceTimelineWeek. If I use the view timeGridWeek it works just fine.
I will leave here the json options I'm working with, but what I'd like to know is if there is another option I can use instead of dayRender for resources in particular.
I've tried resourcesRender, it works for the resource part of the table only. I've tried some of the slot render hooks as well without success.

```
header: {
      left: 'today prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
},
defaultView: 'resourceTimelineWeek',
firstDay: 1,
slotDuration: {day: 1},
minTime: '10:00:00',
maxTime: '18:00:00',
editable: true,
dayRender: function (args) {
    debugger;
    args.el.innerHtml = 'daeda';
},
resourceRender: function(renderInfo) {
    /*renderInfo.el.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';*/
},
resources: [
  { id: 'abc', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium A' },
  { id: 'b', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium B' },
  { id: 'c', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium C' }
]
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: which version of fullCalendar is this? In the current version there is no such option as "dayRender" - https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc . You can add a tag to your question for the relevant version you are using please.

Comment: The version is 4.0.1, I've also added it to the title as I can't create tags that don't already exist. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: It's sufficient to use the existing [fullcalendar-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fullcalendar-4) tag for any 4.x version (as per the description for that tag). We don't need separate tags for point releases, but the main version tags are useful because there are breaking changes between each version, so it changes what the answer to the question might be.

Comment: Anyway it works perfectly well if you use the correct property name `innerHTML` instead of `innerHtml` - JS is case-sensitive. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/JjEQXgo . `debugger;` only works if you have the Developer Tools open and debugging switched on. I'm not sure how you concluded your version works correctly on `timeGridWeek` because it doesn't (demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/GRrbqgE). Voting to close the question as just a typo.

Comment: P.S. Obligatory MDN reference for [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Comment: Even if there is a typo there, which I apologize for, it is not the problem here, The problem is that the debugger does not even proc, which it should despite an erroneous javascript line afterwards.

It does work in the demo you sent, which is leading me to believe it might be a problem with the outsystems forge's calendar wrapper I downloaded.
I will have to dig deeper. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Actually...just noticed something, maybe I was being a little harsh on you. My Codepen used 4.4.0. I've just switched it to 4.0.1 and it reproduces your issue including the debugger issue. Obviously 4.0.1 is very early in the 4.x branch, so there's every chance a bug was fixed in a later update which affected the dayRender callback. I suggest upgrading to the last version of 4.x then you have all the fixes for that branch. Apologies if I was unduly rude - although the typo would still be an issue.

Comment: Yeah I find it pretty weird as well, but I've changed the innerHtml to innerHTML just to test it out, but still no debugger proc or anything happening.
I'm not really sure what I could provide for it, only an OML maybe? But you'd still nee do download the forge's component I'm guessing,
Anyway I don't really want to waste anymore of your time with this issue, as I eventually found a workaround for what I wanted to do.
I left this open in case anyone would come across a similar issue, or had an idea of what could be the problem.
Thank you very much for looking at it.

Comment: Ohh, that would explain it definitely! And it's ok, it could've been an issue with the innerHtml. I wrote that line just to try and trigger something, I didn't even notice the typo tbh, so if it were because of that it would be my bad and shame.
I will take the upgrade into consideration! Once again thank you for your time and attention!

Kind regards